# The request failed for '' (procedure)" because it is a table object - error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have three tables:

- dbo.Student
- dbo.Request
- dbo.RequestLine (which is the associated table between the former two, contains a composite primary key STUD_ID and REQ_ID, and an attribute REQ_DATE)

I am trying to insert records into the `dbo.RequestLine` table. However, I am getting an error saying:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The request for procedure 'RequestLine' failed because 'RequestLine' is a table object.

Here are the DDL statements for the three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Request]
(
    [REQ_ID] [int] IDENTITY(10000005,1) NOT NULL,
    [REQ_STAT] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [REQ_CAT] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [ADMIN_ID] [smallint] NULL,
    [COOR_ID] [smallint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Request] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([REQ_ID] ASC)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Request] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Request_Admin] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ADMIN_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Admin] ([ADMIN_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Request_Admin]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Request]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Request_Coordinator] 
        FOREIGN KEY([COOR_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Coordinator] ([COOR_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Request] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Request_Coordinator]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
    [STUD_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1000009,1) NOT NULL,
    [STUD_NAM] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [STUD_EMAIL] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CAMP_NAM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CAMP_ZIP] [int] NULL,
    [STUD_TYP] [char](5) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([STUD_ID] ASC)
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Student] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_Campus] 
        FOREIGN KEY([CAMP_NAM], [CAMP_ZIP]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Campus] ([CAMP_NAM], [CAMP_ZIP])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Student] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Student_Campus]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestLine]
(
    [STUD_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REQ_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REQ_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_RequestLine] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([STUD_ID] ASC, [REQ_ID] ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RequestLine]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestLine_Request] 
        FOREIGN KEY([REQ_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Request] ([REQ_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RequestLine] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestLine_Request]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RequestLine]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestLine_Student] 
        FOREIGN KEY([STUD_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Student] ([STUD_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RequestLine] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestLine_Student]
GO
```

Here are the three stored procedures I have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Req_InsertNew]
    (@REQ_STAT varchar(12),
     @REQ_CAT varchar(15),
     @ADMIN_ID smallint,
     @COOR_ID smallint)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO dbo.Request (REQ_STAT, REQ_CAT, ADMIN_ID, COOR_ID)
    VALUES (@REQ_STAT, @REQ_CAT, @ADMIN_ID, @COOR_ID);

    DECLARE @REQ_ID INT
    SET @REQ_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SELECT @REQ_ID
END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stud_InsertNew2]
    (@STUD_NAM varchar(30),
     @STUD_EMAIL varchar(50),
     @CAMP_NAM varchar(50),
     @CAMP_ZIP int,
     @STUD_TYP char(5))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temptable TABLE (newSTUDID int, STUDTYPE char);

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO dbo.Student(STUD_NAM, STUD_EMAIL, CAMP_NAM, CAMP_ZIP, STUD_TYP)
    VALUES (@STUD_NAM, @STUD_EMAIL, @CAMP_NAM, @CAMP_ZIP, @STUD_TYP);

    DECLARE @STUD_ID INT
    SET @STUD_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SELECT @STUD_ID
END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReqLine_Insert]
    (@STUD_ID int,
     @REQ_ID int,
     @REQ_DATE date)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.RequestLine (STUD_ID, REQ_ID, REQ_DATE)
    VALUES (@STUD_ID, @REQ_ID, @REQ_DATE)
END
```

And I am trying to use `ExecuteScalar()` to retrieve the `REQ_ID` and `STUD_ID` and put them into the `RequestLine` table.

Here is the C# code:

```
int campzip = int.Parse(ddlCamp.SelectedValue.Trim());
int adminid = int.Parse(ddlAdmin.SelectedValue.Trim());
int coorid = int.Parse(txtCoorID.Text.Trim());

DateTime ReqDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtReqDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);

using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("cis-laredoConnectionString")))
{
    connection.Open();

    var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Stud_InsertNew2", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUD_NAM", txtStdName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUD_EMAIL", txtStdEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAMP_NAM", ddlCamp.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAMP_ZIP", campzip);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUD_TYP", "Other");

    int STUD_ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cmd.Dispose();

    connection.Close();

    connection.Open();

    var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.Req_InsertNew", connection);
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQ_STAT", "Submitted");
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQ_CAT", "Uniform");
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADMIN_ID", adminid);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COOR_ID", coorid);;

    int REQ_ID = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();

    cmd1.Dispose();
    connection.Close();

    // post back info. to dbo.RequestLine table in sql server
    connection.Open();

    var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.ReqLine_Insert", connection);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUD_ID", STUD_ID);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQ_ID", REQ_ID);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@REQ_DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = ReqDate;

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.Dispose();

    connection.Close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error is literally telling you the problem here. You have the SQL `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestLine](...` but you have the C# code `var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.RequestLine", connection); cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` As the error says... *"The request for procedure 'RequestLine' failed because 'RequestLine' is a table object."*

Comment: Thank you for pointing out!! I changed to SqlCommand ("dbo.ReqLine_Insert", connection), now its working!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: The article you shared is very useful! I did have problems with .AddwithValue() especially when I tried to add Date and some other data type such as tinyint. I will change all the codes to Add(,SqlDbType.Datatype).Value. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this:

```
var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.RequestLine", connection);
```

with this:

```
var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.ReqLine_Insert", connection);
```

The object `dbo.RequestLine` is a table, whereas you need the stored procedure `dbo.ReqLine_Insert` for inserting data to this table.